# How to migrate multiple databases in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am doing a project with Django, there are too much data so that I need to form different databases to store them. I made a database router for each app to match the unique database, but when I migrate them, all of the tables were migrate to the same database, here are the codes:

```py
from django.conf import settings

DATABASE_MAPPING = settings.DATABASES_APPS_MAPPING

class DatebaseAppsRouter(object):
    """
    该类为连接不同数据库的路由,在setting中通过设置DATABASE_MAPPING来匹配数据库
    例:
    DATABASE_APPS_MAAPING = {"app1":"db1", "app2":"db2"}
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **kwargs):
        """将所有读操作指向指定的数据库"""
        if model._meta.app_label in DATABASE_MAPPING:
            return DATABASE_MAPPING[model._meta.app_label]
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **kwargs):
        """将所有写操作指向指定的数据库"""
        if model._meta.app_label in DATABASE_MAPPING:
            return DATABASE_MAPPING[model._meta.app_label]
        return None


    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **kwargs):
        """允许使用相同数据库的应用程序之间的任何关系"""
        db_obj1 = DATABASE_MAPPING.get(obj1._meta.app_label)
        db_obj2 = DATABASE_MAPPING.get(obj2._meta.app_label)
        if db_obj1 and db_obj2:
            if db_obj1 == db_obj2:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return None


    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        """确保这些应用程序只出现在相关的数据库中"""
        if db in DATABASE_MAPPING.values():
            return DATABASE_MAPPING.get(model._meta.app_label) == db
        elif model._meta.app_label in DATABASE_MAPPING:
            return False
        return None


    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **kwargs):
        """确保身份验证应用程序只出现在login数据库中"""
        if db in DATABASE_MAPPING.values():
            return DATABASE_MAPPING.get(app_label) == db
        elif app_label in DATABASE_MAPPING:
            return False
        return None
```

By using the router, I would like to migrate multiple databases, but it doesn't work

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W001) Your URL pattern '^login/$' uses include with a route ending with a '$'. Remove the dollar from the route to avoid problems including URLs.
?: (urls.W001) Your URL pattern '^main/$' uses include with a route ending with a '$'. Remove the dollar from the route to avoid problems including URLs.
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'admin' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: Themepark, admin, auth, contenttypes, ginseng_holding_hotel, holiday_resort, login, nature_scenic_area, sessions, the_scent_spot_trusteeship, tourist_communications, travel_agency
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

So how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your app name with 'your_app' and the database you want to run the migration on with 'your_app_respective_db' from the mapping you have. Hope this helps.

```sh
python manage.py migrate your_app --database your_app_respective_db
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved this problem perfectly!

Comment: @EzioHebe Glad this solved the issue. If this helped you out and work, consider accepting the answer. It will be helpfull for others in the future if anyone has same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem is with your urls.py
>
> If you are using `django.urls.path()` you don't have to add the carrot sign and the dollar sign and do it this way.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('main/', views.main, name='main'),
]
```

> But if you were using `django.urls.url()` then you should do this

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^main/', views.main, name='main'),
]
```

if you don't mind, can you show us your urls.py?

Comment: Of course! But I would like to know how to migrate multiple databases in Django, I don't think it is not relevant to the urls.py. Here is the urls.py :

'''
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Themepark.views import themepark, fetchdata

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url("^$", themepark),
    url("result", fetchdata),
]
'''

Comment: I think the error you have is caused by urls.py and afterward, you can find the answer to the problem you seek.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your different DB details as per your app in `settings.py` as following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': config('DATABASE_PORT'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
    },
    'app1_name': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config('APP1_DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': config('DATABASE_PORT'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
    },
    'app2_name': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config('APP2_DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': config('DATABASE_PORT'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
    }
}
```

`default` will be your main app. Also when you do migrations and migrate, you need to mention the database name like following.

```
python manage.py makemigrations app1
python manage.py migrate app1 --database=app1
```